# Rare infinite loop in code, don't want to wait for it to happen again

Tags: java, netbeans, loops, debugging, infinite

Ok, so I've got a genetic algorithm running in netbeans, and its been running for like 5 hours and seems to have entered an infinite loop. Is there any way that I can attach a debugger to it? or at least get some clue as to where it is in the code? I'd rather not sit around for another 5 hours while I wait for it to happen again.

Comment: there's no need for code here, he's simply asking if he can attach a debugger at runtime. upvoted the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way to get some basic information from your running program is to run [`jstack`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) on it, it will print stack traces of all threads in your code. Do that several times and you should have a good idea what is wrong.

Use [`jps`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) to find out the id of your JVM like and then use `jstack` with that ID:

```
$ jps
10664 Jps
7141 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110124-0830.jar
$ jstack 7141
```

[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) provides similar information, if you prefer a GUI application.

Comment: ill give it a shot, gotta go figure out what jstack is though :)

Comment: VisualVM (part of the JDK) is also able to produce a stacktrace

Comment: Yes, it's probably easier. I'm just used to having to do that with servers that are behind restrictive firewalls and low-bandwidth connections. In those cases `jstack` is much easier to handle ;-)